# XAML Character Spacing Property Not working on Integers

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an project where I am trying to adjust the CharacterSpacing property of a TextBlock element.

It seems to work fine until I change the text value to an Integer.

Has this been happened to anyone else? Is there a workaround?

Here is a screenshot and code Snippet per Max's comment:

[image]

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CharacterBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,-27,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="316" FontSize="72""/>
<TextBlock x:Name="NumberBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,193,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterSpacing="613" FontSize="72"/>
```

Note the character spacing is applied to both TextBlocks, but only visible on the CharacterBlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue that was introduced in Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 applications as noted by other users on [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/15432b64-9600-4a9b-8874-d621888597d6/) msdn page.

There is no workaround that I know of except... well I'm almost embarrassed just to suggest it, but if you ABSOLUTELY MUST HAVE the numbers closer you could put each letter in a TextBlock all inside of a StackPanel and use negative left and right margins. Yuck.

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking of doing, but kinda lame to do so

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve the character spacing problem if you have any, is to go blend and change the template properties. it varies on how you want some properties and hence we cannot tell you what to do other shifting to an another IDE. Blend looks better and it is even nice when we need to change the properties and all. While visual studio is mainly when you wanted to do some hard coding.

Comment: My problem is, the character spacing on a TextBlock templates does not get applied to integers, only alphabetical characters. Editing the template does not solve this.

Comment: I don't get you. Please leave a screenshot of what you get. Its basically good by default.